# How should 'missing' request headers be handled by a Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, error-handling, controller

I am writing a Spring Boot application. My controller has 2 custom request headers. I was executing a couple of tests only to find out that my application returns a '404' when the headers are not present.

I however was expecting this to lead to a '400' error?

Can anyone elaborate why this is happening? And how I should handle it properly? As in tell the consumer of the service the headers are missing?

```
@RestController("fundsConfirmationController")
@RequestMapping(
    value="/accounts/{accountId}/funds-confirmations",
    headers = {"X-CAF-MSGID", "X-AccessToken"}
) 
public class FundsConfirmationController implements FundsConfirmationControllerI{

private FundsConfirmationServiceI fundsConfirmationService;

@Autowired
public FundsConfirmationController(FundsConfirmationServiceI fundsConfirmationService){
    this.fundsConfirmationService = fundsConfirmationService;
}

@GetMapping(
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<?> fundsConfirmation(@RequestHeader(value="X-CAF-MSGID") String messageId,
                                           @RequestHeader(value="X-AccessToken") String accessToken,
                                           FundsConfirmationRequest requestParams) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 solutions to do the same.

First using `@RequestHeader` with `required` `false`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{blabla}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void post(@RequestHeader(value="X-CAF-MSGID", required=false) String X-CAF-MSGID) {
    if(X-CAF-MSGID == null) {
        // Your JSON Error Handling
    } else {
        // Your Processing
    }
}
```

Second using `HttpServletRequest` instead of `@RequestHeader`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{blabla}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void post(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String X-CAF-MSGID = request.getHeader("X-CAF-MSGID");
    if(X-CAF-MSGID == null) {
        // Your JSON Error Handling
    } else {
        // Your Processing
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP headers count towards defining the end-point by default. They are a further specification as a result a 404 is the appropriate response for a request without said headers. 

Thank you for the response.